# Backup Joomla Site

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

i have a backup file of joomla website generated from akeeba backup from Joomla 1.5. Any body can please tell me how i can restore this website from backup in joomla higher version or latest version . if yes then please tell me how.

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say you will need to rebuild you site.
Hopefully there will be updated versions of your third party components.
If you have a custom made component, you can use http://component-creator.com to import your database structure and recreate a component for 3.x

Answer (score 0):

there is no way, or you would have to dive into structure and specifics of the Jos DB. For example you could use the code in JUpgrade and run that locally, but that would be a lot of work. ( although someone may already have done it before )
A much simpler solution is to restore it back into a new Joomla 1.5 instance and then apply the JUpgrade component, that is no longer on the official extensions site, but you can still download it from some support websites. Don't forget to do the manual replacement of mootools.js first otherwise the JUpgrade does not work.